# Property declared dynamically

Tags: magento2

I just found some code like the following.  `$this->_curl` is this kind of variable to declare before the constructor, and in phpstorm it shows `Property declared dynamically`, is this good practice or bad practice, will it cause any problems?

```
class customHelper extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){
        $this->_curl=$curl;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bad practice because

- all dynamic declared properties are public. you may not want your property to be public.
- starting php 8.2 this will raise a deprecation warning so you will have to revisit this code later
- starting php 9.0 this will throw an error.
- it just looks bad

You can avoid all this by declaring your propery

```
private $_curl;
```

or if you want it strong typed (php 7.4+)

```
private \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $_curl;
```

Bonus, you may want to drop the underscores because PSR recommends to not use underscores (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#42-properties). just call it `$curl`.